# Use MySql vs json file for user database for python telegram bot

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am trying to create a support telegram bot using pytelegrambotapi. While I was making it, I met a problem. There a lot of global variables appeared in my code and I want to systematize it. I searched about this in internet and found few solutions: to make a json serializable class and save all data in json file or to make a database of all users using MySql. But I don't know what is better. The amount of users, who will use a bot will be about 100-150, so what is the better solution for my telegram bot? thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are ok, but if you want to increase the number of users you have to use database for integrity and consistency